# Spring JDBC - prevent logging - INFO: Added default SqlReturnUpdateCount parameter named #update-count-1

Tags: spring, logging, spring-jdbc

My standalone application uses Spring JDBC.

I see a lot of the following statements in System.out

```
Mar 28, 2013 6:42:12 PM org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate extractReturnedResults
INFO: Added default SqlReturnUpdateCount parameter named #update-count-1
```

How do I prevent these logs?

Comment: Remove `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` (possibly less) from your loggers.

Comment: There is no log4j.properties file at all

Comment: Then it's probably using commons-logging by default, search around on how to disable that, I'm not exactly sure. Or add log4j/logback and put your own logging configuration.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252743/change-spring-framework-log-level-in-simple-example-project) and see if it works :)

Answer (score 3):

I got around this by skipping the undeclared results, which I don't need anyway

```
JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jt.setSkipUndeclaredResults(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the function call in the following format:

```
Select function_name(args) from dual;
```

With the above query, you can use any matching function in JdbcTemplate

Hope this helps you solve the issue.