# Logging issue with Spring (core & jdbc not MVC)

Tags: java, spring, logging, jdbc, log4j

My application is using `Spring` to handle the interaction with database (`Sql Server`)

And `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar`, `log4j-1.2.17.jar`, `slf4j-api-1.6.3.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar` are put into build path for the logging framework of the application.

The last two logging jar (`slf4j-api` and `slf4j-log4j12`) are for another component inside the application to use `log4j`.

Here is my questions:

1. When `Spring-Jdbc` runtime excecption happens, the exception is only showed in the console of eclipse with the font color red. The exception is NOT logged into the log file. But the normal log (like `log.info(...)`) are all in the log file. Why can't the run-time exception be in the log file and how to solve this problem.
2. When I use `SimpleJdbcCall` to call the stored procedure with parameters in `MapSqlParameterSource`, the following log shows up:

14:43:30 [INFO ] Added default SqlReturnUpdateCount parameter named #update-count-1

14:43:30 [INFO ] Added default SqlReturnUpdateCount parameter named #update-count-1
......

It's really annoying because the number of this message is so large. I want to turn off this particular log message without affecting another logging with the same level (`INFO`)

And my log4j.xml is fine I think because the logging are basically fine except the above issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Spring is using commons-logging internally that's why you can see the messages in your eclipse console. To redirect commons-logging to slf4j/log4j you need to remove commons-logging-1.1.1.jar from your classpath and add jcl-over-slf4j.jar from your slf4j version. To get rid of the dublicate red eclipse messages (jul and jcl) you can set the logging level in logging.properties for the console handler to warning:

   java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING
2. Second issue was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685354/spring-jdbc-prevent-logging-info-added-default-sqlreturnupdatecount-paramet).

Comment: If commons-logging.jar is removed from classpath, and application will start up with an error: class NOT found...

Comment: Doesnt jcl-over-slf4j.jar include all neccessary classes?